# Get Href and Store into Array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the first youtube video of each  and store them into an array using jQuery?

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dzpkn29_vY"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFCRMonf7lI"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBTUAHGpQqE"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTkPfjSXFpo"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think getting the link would be something like:

```
$('.thumbs li:first-child').attr("href");
```

But how do I get both of them and store them into an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var arr = $('.thumbs > li:first-child > a').map(function() {
    return this.href;
}).toArray();
```

Comment: Awww. I guess that is one of the most elegant solutions I have seen on SO today. Hat tip, man!

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$('#one, #two').find('.thumbs').each(function (index, element) {
    arr[arr.length] = $(this).find('a[href^="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="]').eq(0).attr('href');
});
```

The bonus of using this type of search is that only elements with links to youtube are added to the array.

The `arr` array will now look like this:

```
["http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dzpkn29_vY", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBTUAHGpQqE"]
```

Note that beginning with the `#one` and `#two` elements is not necessary (you can start with `.thumbs`) however this limits the search to only those elements (in-case there are other `.thumbs` elements in the DOM).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fDQ2v/

Comment: Uhmm, sorry if that's a dumb question - but is there any reason for using `arr[arr.length]` rather than `.push()`? I imagine the additional property access on each iteration would have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: Calling `.push` is an unnecessary function call. Using `arr[arr.length]` will speed-things-up in older browsers (in newer browsers I think `.push` is actually faster, but old browsers need the help more than new ones). Not a dumb question at all.

Comment: At least when running chrome nighty, there's no measurable difference at all. Firefox even appears to handle `.push()` faster. The effect is pretty negligible in any case. http://jsperf.com/arr-push-vs-arr-arr-length http://jsperf.com/push-vs-array-array-length **Edit:** Ah, the older browsers.

Comment: This JSPerf removes the extra code (that will perform differently in different browses): http://jsperf.com/arr-push-vs-arr-length. Run this JSPerf in IE8 or IE7 and `.push()` will come-out quite a bit slower.